# How can I apply code from CodePen.io to my Divi WP website?

Tags: css, wordpress, web, codepen, divi

I am trying to use some button styles I found on CodePen.io on my website. I am building in using Divi and WordPress. Any help is greatly appreciated. The code from CodePen is https://codepen.io/b1tn3r/pen/YjOzRv and the code is the following:

I only added CSS. I can't add more or it won't let me post.

CSS:

```
//
// ---Retro Button---
//
.retro-btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: 0 0;
  
  &.lg {
    .btn {
      width: 294px;
      height: 54px;
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 50px;
      
      .btn-inner .content-wrapper .btn-content .btn-content-inner:before {
        padding-top: 0;
        letter-spacing: .15em;
      }
    }
  }
  &.sm {
    .btn {
      width: 165px;
      height: 37px;
      font-size: 10.5px;
      line-height: 32.5px;

      .btn-inner .content-wrapper .btn-content .btn-content-inner:before {
        padding-top: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  &.primary {
    .btn .btn-inner .content-wrapper {
      &:before {
        background-color: #051D41;
      }
      .btn-content {
        background-color: #0d47a1;
      }
    }
  }
  &.secondary {
    .btn .btn-inner .content-wrapper {
      &:before {
        background-color: #263238;
      }
      .btn-content {
        background-color: #37474F;
      }
    }
  }
  &.danger {
    .btn .btn-inner .content-wrapper {
      &:before {
        background-color: #590000;
      }
      .btn-content {
        background-color: #CC0000;
      }
    }
  }
  &.warning {
    .btn .btn-inner .content-wrapper {
      &:before {
        background-color: #6A3800;
      }
      .btn-content {
        background-color: #FF8800;
      }
    }
  }
  &.success {
    .btn .btn-inner .content-wrapper {
      &:before {
        background-color: #00481F;
      }
      .btn-content {
        background-color: #009A3E;
      }
    }
  }
  &.info {
    .btn .btn-inner .content-wrapper {
      &:before {
        background-color: #164E62;
      }
      .btn-content {
        background-color: #33b5e5;
      }
    }
  }

  .btn {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 3px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-rendering: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .1s ease-out;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

    // size
    width: 240px;
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration-color: initial;
    border-color: initial;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

    &, &:focus {
      outline-color: 0;
      outline-style: none;
      outline-width: 0;
    }

    &:hover {
      .btn-content-inner:before {
        background-color: rgba(13,13,13,.1);
      }
    }

    &:before {
      content: " ";
      background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, .3);
      width: calc(100% - 2px);
      height: calc(100% - 4px);
      bottom: -1px;
      left: 1px;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 3px;
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-transition: background .12s ease-out, -webkit-transform .12s ease-out;
      transition: background .12s ease-out, -webkit-transform .12s ease-out;
      transition: transform .12s ease-out, background .12s ease-out;
      transition: transform .12s ease-out, background .12s ease-out, -webkit-transform .12s ease-out;
    }

    &.btn-left {
      &:before {
        -webkit-transform: skewY(1deg) translate3d(0,-.5px,0);
        transform: skewY(1deg) translate3d(0,-.5px,0);
      }

      .btn-content {
        -webkit-transform: skewY(-1deg);
        transform: skewY(-1deg);
      }
    }

    &.btn-right {
      &:before {
        -webkit-transform: skewY(-1deg) translate3d(0,-.5px,0);
        transform: skewY(-1deg) translate3d(0,-.5px,0);
      }

      .btn-content {
        -webkit-transform: skewY(1deg);
        transform: skewY(1deg);
      }
    }

    &.btn-center {
      &:before {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-1px,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,-1px,0);
      }

      .btn-content {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,1px,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,1px,0);
      }
    }

    &.btn-active {
      .btn-inner .content-wrapper .btn-content {
        -webkit-transition: background .12s ease-out,color .12s ease-out,-webkit-transform .12s ease-out;
        transition: background .12s ease-out,color .12s ease-out,-webkit-transform .12s ease-out;
        transition: transform .12s ease-out,background .12s ease-out,color .12s ease-out;
        transition: transform .12s ease-out,background .12s ease-out,color .12s ease-out,-webkit-transform .12s ease-out;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,2px,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,2px,0);

        .btn-content-inner {
          opacity: .1;
        }
      }

      &:before {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-3px,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,-3px,0);
      }
    }

    .btn-inner {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;

      .content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        font-family: inherit;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 3px);
        margin-top: -3px;

        &:after, &:before, 
        & .btn-content:after, 
        & .btn-content:before, 
        & .btn-content .btn-content-inner:before {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
        }

        &:before {
          background-image: initial;
          background-color: #004d40;

          content: " ";
          border-radius: 3px;
          top: auto;
          bottom: -3px;
          z-index: 1;
          -webkit-transition: background .185s ease-out, -webkit-transform .185s ease-out;
          transition: background .185s ease-out, -webkit-transform .185s ease-out;
          transition: transform .185s ease-out, background .185s ease-out;
          transition: transform .185s ease-out, background .185s ease-out, -webkit-transform .185s ease-out;
        }

        &:after {
          background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.15);

          content: " ";
          border-radius: 3px;
          z-index: 3;
          width: 0;
          top: 2px;
        }

        .btn-content {
          background-image: initial;
          background-color: #26a69a;
          color: #ebf1f8;

          position: relative;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
          -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
          -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
          border-radius: 3px;
          text-indent: 0;
          z-index: 3;
          overflow: hidden;
          padding: 0 16px;
          -webkit-transition: border .185s ease-out,background .185s ease-out,color .185s ease-out,-webkit-transform .185s ease-out;
          transition: border .185s ease-out,background .185s ease-out,color .185s ease-out,-webkit-transform .185s ease-out;
          transition: border .185s ease-out,transform .185s ease-out,background .185s ease-out,color .185s ease-out;
          transition: border .185s ease-out,transform .185s ease-out,background .185s ease-out,color .185s ease-out,-webkit-transform .185s ease-out;
          
          &:before, &:after {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .1125s ease-out .05s, -webkit-transform .185s ease-out .05s;
            transition: opacity .1125s ease-out .05s, -webkit-transform .185s ease-out .05s;
            transition: transform .185s ease-out .05s, opacity .1125s ease-out .05s;
            transition: transform .185s ease-out .05s, opacity .1125s ease-out .05s, -webkit-transform .185s ease-out .05s;
          }

          &:before {
            content: " ";
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,50%,0);
          }

          &:after {
            content: " ";
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
          }


          .btn-content-inner {
            display: block;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 75ms ease-out .1125s;
            transition: opacity 75ms ease-out .1125s;

            &:before {
              content: attr(label);
              padding-top: 9.5px;
              font-size: .8em;
              font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
              letter-spacing: .06em;
              -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out, background-color .1125s ease-in;
              transition: opacity .3s ease-out, background-color .1125s ease-in;
              opacity: 1;
              z-index: -1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well.. the general answer is that you have to handle it in respect to wordpress theme development.  That effort itself would be considered off-topic to SO (according to the wordpress attribute you've tagged).  This question could be considered on-topic to wordpress.stackexchange.com, but in respect to you doing that effort: doing theme development.  You should make the attempt to handle these changes in a theme first and pose your question to that community when you run into issues in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom CSS to a Wordpress site using the Divi theme by:

1. Go "Divi" in the left hand menu of the admin area
2. Select "Theme Options"
3. Under the "General Tab" scroll down to where it says "Custom CSS"
4. Enter your CSS in the text box to the right there.
5. Click "Save Changes"